# Differences in Macros and Reflection in Meta-Programming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reflection, macros

I'm currently studying about Meta-Programming. I guess Ruby on Rails uses meta-programming heavily. Here is what I understand so far.

- Macros: Happens in compile-time, uses code to generate code (i.e. Rails uses attr_reader to automatically set up getters)
- Reflection: Happens in run-time (I read reflection uses it's own language as a meta-language, but not sure what this means)
- Meta-Programming uses a program as a data type to generate code; Macros and Reflection are techniques of Meta-Programming in some sense.

I have total 3 questions.

1. I am having hard time to understand what Reflection is. Can someone provide me a good definition of it with maybe applicable examples?
2. What's the difference between Macros and Reflection
3. Whether I can see Macros and Reflection as a subset of Meta-Programming since the definition of Macros and Meta-Programming almost seems identical to me.

If you can explain this in using Ruby/Rails, that would help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: The first point is not a question, the second has been answered by yourself already, the third can only be answered by yourself, once you have an actual programming task (instead of a “I want to do meta programming attitude”)…

Comment: As said, it depends on the actual task you want to solve. For some of them, it might be clear which approach is better suited, for others, it might be subjective or depend on a trade-off driven by a personal focus.

Comment: Besides the fact that your question is unclear, and also way too broad, there is also the rather practical problem that Ruby doesn't have macros, so how do you expect us to explain macros using Ruby?

Comment: Yeah I was assuming that the question is very broad but that was the only way to describe since I just got to learn the concept of it and do not know how to ask detailed questions around this topic! I will study more on my own to ask more specified questions.

Answer (score 2):

Meta-programming is using a program to manipulate a program. It is a very broad definition indeed, and pushing it to the extreme may even include automatic debugging and binary patch development.

The most obvious difference between macro and reflection is that the former uses a meta-language different than the object language (language which is manipulated), while the latter uses the object language itself as the meta-language. Besides, macros are more often associated with generation, such as conditional compilation and template expansion; reflection with inspection and manipulation, such as member iteration and bypassing privacy restriction. But the more one dives in the more blurry the boundary is.

In terms of Ruby on Rails, the most popular meta-programming pattern is probably ActiveRecord. It uses reflection to list classes and class members it needs to map to database tables and columns. Similarly, any ORM project involves a fair bit of meta-programming.

Rails uses meta-programming in a lot of other ways, but I am not familiar enough with it to know. I stumbled upon this blogpost in research which might help: [Metaprogramming Ruby and Rails Antipatterns (Part 1 of 2)](https://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/04/29/metaprogramming-ruby-and-antipatterns-in-rails/). You can define methods with names only known at runtime and define attributes on-demand with meta-programming.

Because meta-programming is such an overarching concept, I generally summarize it as "customizing compiler / runtime". In the end, if you are trying to do something that needs information from the compiler or the runtime, a.k.a. from the running code itself, that is probably meta-programming.

Comment: Reflection does *not* use a "meta-language"; it uses the same language syntax and semantics as anything else.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks for clarifying that in reflection the meta-language uses the same syntax and semantics as the object language. I overlooked this.